# GoodData: "CloudConnect" or another tool for ETL development

Tags: etl, gooddata, cloud-connect

We are GoodData customers who are beginning the process of evaluating ETL tools other than CloudConnect.  I'd like some recommendations from other GoodData customers who do their own ETL/LDM development with a tool other than CloudConnect.  What has been your experience with these other tools?  How do they compare with CloudConnect?  I have another conversation going on LinkedIn (https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Model-ETL-Development-CloudConnect-vs-6616061.S.5897711443083538433?qid=fbab6f85-4bd2-4515-8737-98a365bf9208&trk=groups_most_popular-0-b-ttl&goback=%2Egmp_6616061).  From this conversation I have learned a lot about Keboola but I would like to hear others' experiences with other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use our "BI Automation Framework" that is being developed on the top of our [Ruby SDK](http://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ruby) and it is great fit if you are more "Developer/Coder". It will be integrated with our [Agile DataWarehouse Service (ADS)](https://developer.gooddata.com/article/agile-data-warehousing-service-tutorial-for-beginners) where you have option to manage your data transformation process using the Vertica database with SQL. We are moving forward quickly in this space.

Another option you can use is to use the ADS + CloudConnect as orchestration tool. Again, this helps you when doing SQL transformation is more comfortable for you. If you want to start testing those tools, let me know.

JT